# filtering array with multiple same properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, lookup, reduce

so I have an array of values like this

```
const foodsList = [
  {
    foodOrigin: "Padang",
    foodName: "Nasi Padang",
    originCode: "PDN"
  },
  {
    foodOrigin: "Padang",
    foodName: "Gulai",
    originCode: "PDN"
  },
  {
    foodOrigin: "Padang",
    foodName: "Rendang",
    originCode: "PDN"
  },
  {
    foodOrigin: "Palembang",
    foodName: "Pempek",
    originCode: "PLG"
  },
  {
    foodOrigin: "Palembang",
    foodName: "Tekwan",
    originCode: "PLG"
  },
  {
    foodOrigin: "Yogyakarta",
    foodName: "Gudeg",
    originCode: "YKT"
  }
];
```

and I want to filter the array so the result would be like this instead

```
const filteredFoodsList = [
  {
    foodOrigin: "Padang",
    originCode: "PDN"
  },
  {
    foodOrigin: "Palembang",
    originCode: "PLG"
  },
  {
    foodOrigin: "Yogyakarta",
    originCode: "YKT"
  }
];
```

In order to achieve the result, I tried doing it like below but is there a cleaner and better way to do this? ( especially since my actual array's data consist of more than 500 )

```
const filteredFoodsList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < foodsList.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    filteredFoodsList.push({
      originCode: foodsList[i].originCode,
      foodOrigin: foodsList[i].foodOrigin
    });
  }
  let isExist = false;
  for (let j = 0; j < filteredFoodsList.length; j++) {
    if (foodsList[i].originCode === filteredFoodsList[j].originCode) {
      isExist = true;
    }
  }
  if (!isExist) {
    filteredFoodsList.push({
      originCode: foodsList[i].originCode,
      foodOrigin: foodsList[i].foodOrigin
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: [Possible solution](https://jsbin.com/wewovifiru/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: which `originCode` do you want to get, the first one or the last one?

Comment: @NinaScholz i guess that's an error in the test data, `originCode` should be the same for all foodOrigins

Comment: @Yousaf thank you yousaf for your solution, I appreciate it

Comment: @NinaScholz It's the last one. I've made a mistake and made the first array different from the other ones even though it's supposed to have the same properties as the other values.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Will do, Alexander. I appreciate your solution along with the explanations as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the OP stated there should be some focus on performance, so..

The `Map` could be the fastest way to collect unique values.
(I've borrowed `Array.from(map, ([originCode, foodOrigin]) => ({ foodOrigin, originCode }))` from Nina's answer, really elegant).

But it doesn't affect the performance since the resulting array should be quite small.

But she forgot to include a `Map::has()` check that really improves the performance significantly.

What's important is how fast the source array is iterated. As always I see there can't be a faster thing than `for(let i = 0; ...)`...

```js
const foodsList=[{foodOrigin:"Padang",foodName:"Gulai",originCode:"PDN"},{foodOrigin:"Padang",foodName:"Rendang",originCode:"PDN"},{foodOrigin:"Palembang",foodName:"Pempek",originCode:"PLG"},{foodOrigin:"Palembang",foodName:"Tekwan",originCode:"PLG"},{foodOrigin:"Yogyakarta",foodName:"Gudeg",originCode:"YKT"}];

const map = new Map;
for (let i = 0; i < foodsList.length; i++) {
    const item = foodsList[i];
    map.has(item.originCode) || map.set(item.originCode, item.foodOrigin);
}

const result = Array.from(map, ([originCode, foodOrigin]) => ({ foodOrigin, originCode }));

console.log(result);
```

And a benchmark:

```
` Chrome/121
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                         n=10000     |   n=100000    |   n=1000000    |  n=10000000  
Alexander's solution   1.23x x10k 526 | 1.00x x1k 518 | 1.00x x100 543 | 1.00x x10 554
Nina's improved        1.00x x10k 429 | 1.35x x1k 700 | 1.32x x100 717 | 1.31x x10 727
Peter's solution       1.00x x10k 427 | 1.44x x1k 746 | 1.35x x100 732 | 1.37x x10 760
Nina's solution        1.23x x10k 524 | 1.55x x1k 801 | 1.50x x100 815 | 1.46x x10 811
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/122
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                         n=10000     |    n=100000    |   n=1000000    |  n=10000000  
Alexander's solution   1.00x x10k 355 | 1.00x  x1k 363 | 1.00x x100 383 | 1.00x x10 380
Nina's improved        3.63x  x1k 129 | 3.64x x100 132 | 3.86x  x10 148 | 3.68x  x1 140
Peter's solution       4.00x  x1k 142 | 3.55x x100 129 | 3.39x  x10 130 | 3.95x  x1 150
Nina's solution        4.08x  x1k 145 | 4.16x x100 151 | 3.97x  x10 152 | 4.03x  x1 153
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script>

    const chunk = [{ foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Gulai", originCode: "PDN" }, { foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Rendang", originCode: "PDN" }, { foodOrigin: "Palembang", foodName: "Pempek", originCode: "PLG" }, { foodOrigin: "Palembang", foodName: "Tekwan", originCode: "PLG" }, { foodOrigin: "Yogyakarta", foodName: "Gudeg", originCode: "YKT" }];
    const $chunk = [];
    let count = 2000;
    while (count--) {
        $chunk.push(...chunk);
    }
    const $input = [];
    const foodsList = $input;
    
    // @benchmark Peter's solution

    foodsList
      .reduce((collector, { foodOrigin, originCode = null }) => {

        if (originCode !== null && !collector.lookup.has(foodOrigin)) {

          collector.lookup.set(foodOrigin, true);
          collector.result.push({
            foodOrigin,
            originCode,
          });
        }
        return collector;

      }, { lookup: new Map, result: [] }).result;

    // @benchmark Nina's solution
    Array.from(
        foodsList.reduce((m, { foodOrigin, originCode }) => m.set(foodOrigin, originCode), new Map),
        ([foodOrigin, originCode]) => ({ foodOrigin, originCode })
    );

    // @benchmark Alexander's solution
    const map = new Map;
    for (let i = 0; i < foodsList.length; i++) {
        const item = foodsList[i];
        map.has(item.originCode) || map.set(item.originCode, item.foodOrigin);
    }

    Array.from(map, ([originCode, foodOrigin]) => ({ foodOrigin, originCode }));

    // @benchmark Nina's improved

    Array.from(
        foodsList.reduce((m, { foodOrigin, originCode }) => {
            m.has(foodOrigin) || m.set(foodOrigin, originCode);
            return m;
        }, new Map),
        ([foodOrigin, originCode]) => ({ foodOrigin, originCode })
    );


</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: I really like the benchmark. It seems the github-repo for it is yours? Could you enhance it with a Readme? Looks really interesting to me!

Comment: @Hellma it's a raw alpha at the moment. yes, i plan to make a readme. i guess you could subscribe to the repo to receive updates. you are the first who asked so i'll make some efforts to make it usable to other folks. additionally i'll notify you here with a comment on any progress. https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark

Comment: I have it starred and watch it. I am looking forward for updates!

Answer (score 3):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get a new array from it.

```js
const
    foodsList = [{ foodOrigin: 'Padang', foodName: 'Gulai', originCode: 'PDN' }, { foodOrigin: 'Padang', foodName: 'Rendang', originCode: 'PDN' }, { foodOrigin: 'Palembang', foodName: 'Pempek', originCode: 'PLG' }, { foodOrigin: 'Palembang', foodName: 'Tekwan', originCode: 'PLG' }, { foodOrigin: 'Yogyakarta', foodName: 'Gudeg', originCode: 'YKT' }],
    result = Array.from(
        foodsList.reduce((m, { foodOrigin, originCode }) => m.set(foodOrigin, originCode), new Map),
        ([foodOrigin, originCode]) => ({ foodOrigin, originCode })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: nice one! i'll benchmark ;-)

Comment: added the benchmark, great to learn from you, thanks

Comment: i just benchmarked yours with the Map::has() check. seems faster. i hope you don't mind. just trying to find the fastest way for our common benefit and learning

Comment: i learn from you you could do the same

Answer (score 2):

You can use an object to store the values

```js
const foodsList = [{
  foodOrigin: 'Padang',
  foodCode: 'SPI',
  foodName: 'Nasi Padang',
}, {
  foodOrigin: 'Padang',
  foodName: 'Gulai',
  originCode: 'PDN',
}, {
  foodOrigin: 'Padang',
  foodName: 'Rendang',
  originCode: 'PDN',
}, {
  foodOrigin: 'Palembang',
  foodName: 'Pempek',
  originCode: 'PLG',
}, {
  foodOrigin: 'Palembang',
  foodName: 'Tekwan',
  originCode: 'PLG',
}, {
  foodOrigin: 'Yogyakarta',
  foodName: 'Gudeg',
  originCode: 'YKT',
}]

const items = {}

for (const item of foodsList) {
  if (item.originCode && !(item.originCode in items)) {
    items[item.originCode] = item
  }
}

const result = Object.values(items).map(({ originCode, foodName }) => ({ originCode, foodName }))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my "old-fashioned" approach without `Map` usage:

```js
const foodsList = [ { foodOrigin: "Padang", foodCode: "SPI", foodName: "Nasi Padang" }, { foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Gulai", originCode: "PDN" }, { foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Rendang", originCode: "PDN" }, { foodOrigin: "Palembang", foodName: "Pempek", originCode: "PLG" }, { foodOrigin: "Palembang", foodName: "Tekwan", originCode: "PLG" }, { foodOrigin: "Yogyakarta", foodName: "Gudeg", originCode: "YKT" }];

const filteredFoodsList = foodsList.reduce(
  (acc, curr) =>
    curr.originCode &&
    !acc.some(a => a?.originCode === curr.originCode)
      ? [...acc, curr]
      : acc,
  []
);

console.log(filteredFoodsList);
```

Comment: Array::some() is slow, the OP mentioned that potentially a big amount of data should be processed

Answer (score 1):

The OP does not [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) because not only the array is effected but also each of the array item's data-structure. It's also not [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping, which would allow the latter (changing an item's data), but always assures the same amount of array items.

The combination of filtering and altering data is a classical [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task.

As for the OP's problem, not only does one need to extract unique item-data from a source-array, one also needs to implement a more bullet-proof solution due to the probable occurrence of incorrect data like ...

```
{ foodOrigin: "Padang", foodCode: "SPI", foodName: "Nasi Padang"` }
```

... versus its correct notation of ...

```
{ foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Nasi Padang", originCode: "SPI" }
```

In order to come up with the least necessary iteration effort, one could implement a single `reduce` task in a way that one passes as the `reduce` method's [2nd parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters) an object-based [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) which features two key-value pairs with the `lookup`-key holding a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)-reference and the `result`-key referencing an array.

With each iteration the callback reducer function receives such an object as its first parameter. It also has to return such an object either with changes to its data or not. The very object's `Map` reference will be used as one of the fastest possible ways of looking up whether a specific data has been already processed. The implementation would use a map's [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) method on that behalf.

In case a data-item of interest has not yet been processed, one would [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) an item specific entry at the very `Map`-based `lookup`. Additionally one would create a new, target-data specific object and push it into the `result`-array.

The latter also features the final result at the `reduce` task's return value.

```js
const foodsList = [{
  foodOrigin: "Padang", foodCode: "SPI", foodName: "Nasi Padang"
  // and not ...
  // // foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Nasi Padang", originCode: "SPI",
}, {
  foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Gulai", originCode: "PDN",
}, {
  foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Rendang", originCode: "PDN",
}, {
  foodOrigin: "Palembang", foodName: "Pempek", originCode: "PLG",
}, {
  foodOrigin: "Palembang", foodName: "Tekwan", originCode: "PLG",
}, {
  foodOrigin: "Yogyakarta", foodName: "Gudeg", originCode: "YKT",
}];

const filteredFoodsList = foodsList
  .reduce((collector, { foodOrigin, originCode = null }) => {

    if (originCode !== null && !collector.lookup.has(foodOrigin)) {

      collector.lookup.set(foodOrigin, true);
      collector.result.push({
        foodOrigin,
        originCode,
      });
    }
    return collector;

  }, { lookup: new Map, result: [] }).result;

console.log({ filteredFoodsList });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: why not using Set? more semantic in your case

Comment: there's a mistake on my part... the first index is supposed to have the same properties as the other indexes but I didn't realize I didn't change it to be like them. That said, thank you for your answer and explanation. In case I might stumble into a situation where I have to extract unique data, I can use your answer as a reference.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ... do you mean the usage of `Set` or are you referring to `collector.lookup.set(foodOrigin, true);` ... the `set` method? What is meant by _"... using ...[it]... more semantic ..."_ in case of the latter?

Comment: @PeterSeliger I mean you use Map as Set in your code - you don't use your map values, they are fake (`true`). So using Set would make the code cleaner imho

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` as follows:

```js
const 
      foodsList = [ { foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Nasi Padang", originCode: "PDN" }, { foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Gulai", originCode: "PDN" }, { foodOrigin: "Padang", foodName: "Rendang", originCode: "PDN" }, { foodOrigin: "Palembang", foodName: "Pempek", originCode: "PLG" }, { foodOrigin: "Palembang", foodName: "Tekwan", originCode: "PLG" }, { foodOrigin: "Yogyakarta", foodName: "Gudeg", originCode: "YKT" } ],
      
      filteredFoodsList = foodsList.reduce(
          (acc, {foodOrigin,originCode}) => acc.find(({originCode:oc}) => oc === originCode) ? acc : [...acc, {foodOrigin,originCode}], []
      );

console.log( filteredFoodsList );
```

Answer (score 0):

This can done a lot more simply by constructing a `Map` from an array, then taking its `values()`.

```js
const foodsList=[{foodOrigin:"Padang",foodName:"Nasi Padang",originCode:"PDN"},{foodOrigin:"Padang",foodName:"Gulai",originCode:"PDN"},{foodOrigin:"Padang",foodName:"Rendang",originCode:"PDN"},{foodOrigin:"Palembang",foodName:"Pempek",originCode:"PLG"},{foodOrigin:"Palembang",foodName:"Tekwan",originCode:"PLG"},{foodOrigin:"Yogyakarta",foodName:"Gudeg",originCode:"YKT"}];
const res = [...new Map(foodsList.map(({foodOrigin, originCode}) => 
              [originCode, {foodOrigin, originCode}])).values()];
console.log(res);
```